# trivial motion identity

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am a bit confused about this trivial identity. We have rotation by $\theta$ and translation with a vector $a$. Can someone provide intuition why this is true?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a bit more information in your question about the definitions of $t_a$ and $\rho_\theta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotation of a vector in 2D by an angle $\theta$ can be thought of as multiplication by $e^{i\theta}$, i.e.
\begin{align*}
\rho_{\theta}(z)&=ze^{i\theta} && \text{(rotation)}\\
\tau_{a}(z)&=z+a && \text{(translation)}
\end{align*}
Thus 
$$\rho_{\theta}\left(\tau_{a}(z)\right)=\rho_{\theta}(z+a)=e^{i\theta}(z+a).$$
And,
$$\tau_{a'}\left(\rho_{\theta}(z)\right)=\tau_{a'}(ze^{i\theta})=ze^{i\theta}+a'.$$
But we are given that $a'=ae^{i\theta}$. Thus the two expressions are equal.

Comment: Oh shit, I just realized that this is why a phase shift on a delta function causes a rotation in the complex plane... sorry for being off topic.

Comment: Thanks, it also can be derived from a simple geometry, from two congruent triangles, one being rotation of another one by the angle $\theta$. I will put my solution later.